# Error in the year representation of new Date() object JS

Tags: javascript

So I do not know if I doing something extremely wrong and stupid but here is my problem.  Basically I am trying to learn the weekday value of the 1st day of the current month. To do this I created a Date object with current year and month but 1 as the date. But here is an interesting situation

```
var x = new Date()
console.log(x.getYear())
```

this prints out 115 to the console. I guess that is how they decided to represent 2000s.  So if I do

```
var x = new Date();
var thismonth = new Date( x.getYear(), x.getMonth(), 1)
console.log(thismonth.getDay())
```

This prints out 5 when it should be printing out 0.Since 1st of Feb was a Sunday. On the other hand
    var x = new Date(2015, 1 ,1 )
    console.log(x.getDay())
prints out 0. So JS represents 2015, 115 but then can not handle its own representation ?

Is this caused by a problem in my browser or is this the general situation >

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: It just happens when you try to get Year. There are similar problems with Date implementations in many languages... In JavaScript... better use moment.js

Comment: -Yeah I know month is 0 based, That is why I am putting 1 for February.
- I will check out moment.js Thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `getFullYear()` instead of `getYear()`. That will return what you are expecting.

Check out the API for more info on what each of the methods actually do.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Notice that the description of `getYear()` is: "Returns the year (usually 2-3 digits) in the specified date according to local time. **Use getFullYear() instead.**" (emphasis added)